# Launch image re-appear after hitting the "Home" button and reopening the app several consecutive times 

Tags: iphone, ios, background, splash-screen

If I press the home button and then re-launch the app, after around 10 times, the application showing splash screen and stuck for a few seconds or even crash.
There's a reason that could happen?

(The app is configured to background)

Comment: What is your implementation of applicationDidEnterBackground method?

Comment: Check the application Delegates...There may be some lines that are not required

Comment: @mvb Nothing - empty implementation

Comment: @Lithu Thiruvathira - Which info?

Comment: Anything in the viewDidDissapear may be, that's causing the weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I use mbprogresshud's third-party code.

And I found a mistake, this code include registration to `UIApplicationBecomeActiveNotification`
and this registration happens again whenever this notification recieved.

so, Caused stack over flow after several time that application move to the background and reopen.

Thanks about your answers.